# JavaFX: I need to set a value from an Event Handler to a variable

Tags: java, javafx, callback, event-handling

I need a way to get the value from a textfield to a variable when a button is clicked.
I understand I may need to use a callback but I have never used one and I am not sure how to implement one in this case.

```
TextField textfield = new TextField();
Button submit = new Button();
int column = 0;
                
submit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        //Take value from textfield and assign to column
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if column is a field, you could do:

```
submit.setOnAction(event -> column = Integer.parseInt(textfield.getText()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a callback. All you have to do is to access the value of the `TextField`.

```java
TextField textfield = new TextField();
Button submit = new Button();
int column = 0;
                
submit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        String valueOfTextField = textfield.getText(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is I can't access valueOfTextField outside of the handle()

Comment: Of course you can't. The scope of `valueOfTextField` is inside `handle`. If you want to access the value outside you have to assign the value to a variable, that's visible outside of `handle`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a class variable

```
Column col = new Column();
                submit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                        int column = Integer.parseInt(textfield.getText());
                        col.setValue(column);
                    }
                    
                    
                });
```